# How to extract a link from another webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have an account with a movie / tv show service which shall remain nameless. There are a few shows that I like to watch, and I've bookmarked all the shows on the site. Usually I just go to the show's page and scroll down to the last link for the latest episode.

I was wondering if there is a way to automate this, by using javascript / jQuery, to get the last link, and automatically go there? Unfortunately the site isn't designed very well, and none of the elements have classes / ids. So the solution would have to use nth / last of type selectors.

How can I extract the link of the last `<a>` tag, from somewhere in the DOM structure, when there are no ids or classes, using javascript / jquery?

EDIT: Below is a sample structure of the html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <body>
            <div>
            </div>
            <ul>
            </ul>
            <ul>
            </ul>
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <table>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <span>
                                                <b>
                                                    <a>Episode 1</a>
                                                </b>
                                                <b>
                                                    <a>Episode 2</a>
                                                </b>
                                                <b>
                                                    <a>Episode 3</a>
                                                </b>
                                                <b>
                                                    <a>...</a>
                                                </b>
                                            </span>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </body>
    </head>
</html>
```

Within that span is the list of episodes, contained within `<b>` elements. Pretty awful markup, I know.

Comment: Can you provide a sample html for the list of episodes?

Comment: *"So the solution would have to use nth / last of type selectors."* <- sounds like a solid plan. What have you tried implementing?

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet, as I'm fairly new to javascript. I will update the post with a sample html structure.

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to [ask a question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), asking us to write the program for you and suggestions are off-topic.

Comment: Your question is too broad for StackOverflow, please read the [Help] and [tour] to find out more. Just a reminder, StackOverflow is not a code writing service, which is what your request sounds like.

Answer (score 0):

Any "last" one of the DOM elements can be retrieved using [.lastChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/lastChild) (JS) or [.last()](https://api.jquery.com/last/) (JQuery). The issue is to find the group of DOM elements, where your target is sitting. And that cannot be answered here, unless we see the source code of the page. So, more info, please.

Answer (score 0):

You can scroll the element into view using something like

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('table table span b a'))
  .pop().scrollIntoView()
```

Based on the HTML structure you've provided, that query *should* be specific enough.

References:

- [Document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
- [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)
- [Array.prototype.pop()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop)
- [Element.scrollIntoView()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)